# Rendering breaks when markdown is incorrectly formatted

Tags: bug, status-completed, markdown

This is my first "bug report" on this meta, please be kind!

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1179789/1931274) answer, the user has posted an answer with a code block marked using `<pre><code>...</code></pre>`.
Below the answer the page's formatting is ruined. (You'll see what I mean if you try to flag this question)

IMO (based on some investigation) the reason for this breaking is the `>` in the markdown.

It seems like the Markdown rendering code has written the initial `<pre><code>` and later, aborted further rendering most likely due to a '>' in the code block. And then div containing post text has been closed. (Unclosed elements code, pre). Thus the page has **invalid HTML code** and the rendering breaks.

Comment: Just some old markdown bug. The answer is posted in 2009. All you need to do is to edit it and undo the edit to re-render the post.

Comment: @Antony But bugs need to be fixed. PS: I've re-formatted the post to overcome (right word?) the bug.

Comment: Did you see that I have fixed it for you? This bug is fixed many years ago, just that the server retained the cached version of the post before the fix. All you need to do is to trigger a re-render and it is done.

Comment: @Antony Umm. No.. I didn't refresh. BTW: How often do you re-render such posts?

Comment: No. Very rarely. You only see these type of posts that are in the early days of the site.

Comment: Ooh. I see. Great! <!--- need chars --->

Comment: See also [a related post on MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/178581/something-funny-happened-here).

Answer (score 5):

Yeah, once in a while we still find posts like that from a long time ago where the bug has long been fixed, but the post needs to be re-rendered. We don't rebuild the HTML of all posts automatically when we fix issues in the Markdown rendering. Quoting my comments from [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/259114/115866),

> We have something like 30 million questions and answers. Let's say 100ms to render a post (I don't know what the average time there is, but the ballpark should be correct), that's about 35 machine-days to re-render them all. Doing something like that for an issue that impacts a very small number of posts and that visibily impacts even fewer is not something we would consider.
>
> Also, for any change to Markdown we make there are posts out there that rely on the old behavior and that look broken after the change. While that is not a good reason not to improve Markdown, it would still be nice not to break those old posts, and by deferring re-rendering to the next time a post is edited (which also means that a human looks at it), we achieve just that.

If you find the odd post with old broken rendering, just submit a token edit to force re-rendering. You can see what the post would look like if re-rendered today but just clicking "edit" and looking at the editor's preview; if you suspect an inconsistency between the preview and the server's rendering, you can look at the revision view, (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/1179789/5) in your case), which never displays the cached HTML but uses the current Markdown version to render (if there actually is a discrepancy between the preview and the server-processed version, please do indeed submit a bug report).